# Big O notation for g(n) > h(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I've got this function:

```
f(n) = g(n) + h(n)
g(n) > h(n)
```

Is this result always correct for Big O notation? `O(g(n))`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, because `g(n) + h(n) < g(n) + g(n) <= 2*g(n)`, so you found a constant `C=2` such that `f(n) <= C*g(n)` (for large enough values of `n`), and by [definition of big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), it means `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))`